# .net command line parameters?

Tags: .net

I have vb app that calls another vb app using Process.Start(PROGRAM). 
My question is how can I pass a parameter to the PROGRAM and how can I intercept it in the PROGRAM?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx

Comment: Usually you can open up the corresponding MSDN article very easily by placing the cursor into `Start` and then pressing `F1`. There you find samples how to use the `Start` method and information on what overloads are available.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a second string with the command line parameters when you call Process Start.

```
proc = process.start(program, parameters)
```

To access the command line parameters in the called program, you can use a loop like this:

```
For Each s In My.Application.CommandLineArgs
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `ProcessStartInfo` class and set the `FileName` property to the name of the VB app, then set the `Arguments` property to the arguments.Assign the property `StartInfo` of the `Process` class to the instance of `ProcessStartInfo` and you're good to go.

From the other VB application use `Args` parameter of the `Main` class which is of a string array to process the arguments.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: >>>Arguments Property...
What/where is this? from here on I'm lost

Comment: @bochur1: Arguments is a property of ProcessStartInfo class in which you instantiate. Dim ps As New ProcessStartInfo()  ps.FileName = "name_of_exe"  ps.Arguments = "exe_arguments"   Dim proc As New Process()   proc.StartInfo = ps    proc.Start